# Doxygen: automatically generate list of references to different classes

Tags: doxygen

I have a project which contains several interface to other programs. These interfaces are defined as classes and spread out over the project.
I wonder whether it is possible that I can set a marker in the class description and doxygen later generates a list of links to all the markers.

e.g:

```
 /** \marker interface **/
   class Interface_01
  {
  }
/** \marker interface **/
class Interface_02
{
}
```

In a different doxygen file:

```
\listmarker interface
```

Which should then lead to something like this in the output:

```
* Interface_01
* Interface_02
```

Comment: You could use [groups](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) to create a "module". If you link to the module page, you get a list of items belonging to the group.

Comment: Which version of doxygen?

Comment: Version is 1.8.11

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks a bit like a problem for `\xrefitem`.

In the documentation:

- the paragraph Aliases with arguments (http://doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html#custcmd_complex).
- the command `\xrefitem` (http://doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem)